# how to work on toolbar navigation and title at middle of action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

How to work on toolbar navigation and title at middle of action bar?
here is the image please help me out ,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this below code:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_other"
    style="@style/ToolBarStyle.Event"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_other_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Support"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/slection_item_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I used this code .it working on my apps.